# Jest Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have situation in my unit test case for a react typescript application, where in my logout function the mocked persistor is returning undefined. bellow are the test and relevant files definitions:

logout function definition:

```
import { AnyAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { Dispatch } from 'react';
import { Persistor } from 'redux-persist';

import * as AuthAction from '../../stores/auth/AuthAction';

export const logout = (persistor: Persistor) => (dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>) => {
  console.log('***persistor***:', persistor.purge());
  persistor
  .purge()
  .then((response) => {
    dispatch(AuthAction.resetAuth());
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .finally(() => {
    // always executed
  });
};
```

Now when I run the tests, it throws me error as “ TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')"

```
   8 |   console.log('***persistor***:', persistor.purge());
   9 |   persistor
> 10 |     .purge()
     |             ^
  11 |     .then((response) => {
  12 |       dispatch(AuthAction.resetAuth());
  13 |     })
```

I'm also logging the the persistor, but for some reason it's returning undefined. I'm not able to figure this one out. Please suggest, the test is defined bellow:

```
import { act, fireEvent, render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { Persistor } from 'redux-persist/lib/types';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import IAuthState from '../../../stores/auth/models/IAuthState';
import SessionTimeout from './SessionTimeout';

jest.useFakeTimers();

describe('SessionTimeout', () => {
  const tempPersistor = {
    persist: jest.fn(),
    purge: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve()), // Return a resolved promise
  } as unknown as Persistor;

  const setup = (persistor: Persistor) => {
    console.log('persistor.purge(): ', persistor.persist());
    interface IStore {
      auth: IAuthState;
    }
    const middlewares = [thunk];
    const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);
    const store = mockStore({
      auth: {
        wbsAccessToken: 'some wbsAccessToken',
        wbsRefreshToken: 'some wbsRefreshToken',
        wbsRefreshExp: 0,
        wbsAccessExp: 0,
        user: {
          id: -1,
          image: ' some image',
          firstName: 'some firstName',
          lastName: 'some lastName',
          email: 'some email',
          verified: false,
        },
      } as IAuthState,
    } as IStore);

    return render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <SessionTimeout auth={(store.getState() as IStore).auth} persistor={persistor} />{' '}
      </Provider>
    );
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    // Mocking the event listeners
    jest.mock('react-redux');
    jest.mock('../../../utilities/eventListenerUtil', () => ({
      addEventListeners: jest.fn(),
      removeEventListeners: jest.fn(),
    }));
    setup(tempPersistor);
  });

  // Running all pending timers and switching to real timers using Jest
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllTimers();
    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
    jest.useRealTimers();
  });

  test('should render without crashing', () => {
    expect(screen).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should render the modal with the session timeout message', async () => {
    // Advance timers to simulate inactivity and trigger the warning
    act(() => {
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(61000); // Simulate 1.0166667 minute passing
    });

    expect(screen.queryByText('Session Timeout')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.queryByText(/You're being timed out due to inactivity/i)).toBeInTheDocument();

    expect(true);
  });

  it('should log off when clicking "Log Off" button', async () => {
    // Advance timers to simulate inactivity and trigger the warning
    act(() => {
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(61000); // Simulate 1.0166667 minute passing
    });

    await fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('Log Off'));

    // Wait for the logout process to complete
    await act(async () => {
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0)); // Allow microtasks to run
      expect(tempPersistor.persist).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```